# "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')" ftp nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ftp, ftp-client

I am struggling with this error since yesterday :
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get').

I am using ftp NodeJS module. I have instanciated an c attribute in my class like this :

```
constructor(){
        this.fileFromFTP = '';
        this.fileFromShop = '';
        this.items = [];
        this.c = new Client();
    }
```

The error comes from this method, on the second line (this.c.get) :

```
refreshStore(){
      this.c.on('ready', function() {
        this.c.get('GCEvo/Product_mdl.csv', function(err, stream) {  
          if (err) throw err;
```

When I hover the this.c.get, I don't get a reference to my c attribute. How can I solve this ?

Thank you!

Comment: `this.c.on('ready', function() {` -> `this.c.on('ready', () => {`